# Session()->put in Laravel puts an array every time I execute it

Tags: arrays, laravel, session

I am trying to push an array of arrays in Laravel `session` and even though it inserts it as expected, it also inserts the array with the key 0 as well:

```
session()->flush();
session()->put('wizard.selectedProjects',$selectedProjects);
session()->put('wizard.projectCount',count($selectedProjects));
session()->put('wizard.currentProject',0);
```

For example:

```
$selectedProjects = [
    'project1' => [ 
        'name' => 'name1', 
        'url'  => 'url1'
    ], 
    'project2' => [
        'name' => 'name2', 
        'url'  => 'url2'
    ]
]
```

The `session` would look like this:

`session()->all()` where `wizard` key will have values:

```
0 => ['project1','project2']
```

and also

```
'selectedProjects' => ['project1','project2']
```

Why is Laravel inserting that `0` key with my array and inserting the array at the given key as expected as well?

EDIT: It seems that every time `session()->put()` is executed (in the above code), a new key is generated with the contents of `$selectedProjects`. So in the end I get `0`,`selectedProjects`,`1`,`projectCount`,`2`,`currentProject` as keys in my `session`, all of the extra keys containing `$selectedProjects`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `session()->push()` if you want to add array values. Use `put()` for single values.

```
session()->flush();
session()->push('wizard.selectedProjects', $selectedProjects);
session()->put('wizard.projectCount', count($selectedProjects));
session()->put('wizard.currentProject', 0);
```

Comment: I get the same problem when using push(), be it for all lines or only the first one.

Comment: After restarting the server, I see it works if I use put for all.